# Create Folders within SubFolders

Tags: python, directory, os.walk, subdirectory

I am new to python and I am looking for a way to create subfolders within subfolders. My file tree looks like this:

```
>> Main Folder
   >> Folder a
      >> Folder 1
      >> Folder 2
   >> Folder b
      >> Folder 1
      >> Folder 2
```

I am looking for a way to create a new folder in the bottom most level (folder 1 and folder 2).

I've tried using os.walk and os.path, like this

```
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(current_path):
    for subdir in subdirs:
        filePath = os.path.abspath(subdir)
        newFolder = (filePath + "/new")
        if not os.path.exists(newFolder):
            os.mkdir(newFolder)
```

But this only creates the new folder in the second level (Folder a and Folder b), then gives me the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/diunt-02/Desktop/Brown_Brothers/TEST/new/new'

I think that the loop is making new folders, and the os.walk can't find a path to them. Are there any suggestions for getting os.walk to move into the next level down and create a folder there?

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Does it give a line number?

Comment: in addition, stick with `os.path.join` for new path

Comment: Thanks for the help! I get the error at the os.mkdir(newFolder) line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to create a subdirectory in every grandchild of the root directory, using `os.walk` is just going to make things more confusing. I'll explain why, but first, I'll explain the easier way.

Just explicitly loop two levels down:

```
for child in os.scandir(current_path):
    if child.is_dir():
        for grandchild in os.scandir(child.path):
            newpath = os.path.join(grandchild.path, 'new')
            os.path.mkdir(newpath)
```

---

Now, why is your existing code broken?

`walk` walks the whole tree. It visits the root, and the children, and the grandchildren, and the great-grandchildren, and even the new grandchildren that you create while you're in the middle of walking.

For example, try this:

```
for dirpath, _, _ in os.walk(current_path):
    print(dirpath)
```

What you get is:

```
.
./Folder b
./Folder b/Folder 2
./Folder b/Folder 1
./Folder a
./Folder a/Folder 2
./Folder a/Folder 1
```

It's mixing all the different "levels" together. But you don't want to do the same thing at every level. You only want to create new directories in the grandchildren, not the children, and not the great-grandchildren, and especially not any descendants that you create along the way.

Sure, you can try to keep track of the level as you go up and down, or you can probably see how you could recreate it on the fly from the `dirpath`, but why? If you want to do something exactly 2 levels down, don't loop over all levels and then test for level 2, just go 2 levels down.

Comment: That's very helpful and well explained! I knew that I needed to get down a level farther but I just could quite figure out how. You've explained it really well!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've ended up with that works pretty well! Thanks to @abarnert for the great explanation of why os.walk wasn't useful!

```
for child in os.scandir(current_path):
if child.is_dir():
    for grandchild in os.scandir(child.path):
        # newpath = os.path.join(grandchild.path, 'new')
        # os.mkdir(newpath)
        if grandchild.is_dir():
            newpath = os.path.join(grandchild.path, 'new')
            os.mkdir(newpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs). It automatically creates necessary parent folders.

```
path = 'Main Folder/Folder a/Folder 1'
if not (os.path.exists(path)):
    os.makedirs(path)
```

You can use it in a recursive way for you problem.